# Load single post using Ajax for WPML based site

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I want to load single posts into an index page using Ajax for a WPML based site that I'm working on. Not sure what I'm missing but there seems to be a catch when using multiple languages and fetching the correct posts.

Here's the code I wrote -

```
function loadProject(reference) {
    console.log(window.location.origin + '/references/' + reference);
    // Displays "http://mysite.com/references/example-post/", which exists

    $('#content').load(window.location.origin + '/references/' + reference, function() {
        console.log('Load was performed.');
    });
}
```

I don't reach the JS log after load() but I don't receive any error message either (e.g. "File not found").
"References" is a custom post type that I've created using the Types plugin, and has a file of it's own called single-references.php. I'm not entirely sure how CPTs work with WPML, and that's probably where the problem lies. I have two languages, Swedish and English, and the CPT only has one slug for its kind ("references").

[Solved]
 Used the .get() method instead to retrieve the post and now it works.

Comment: Did you take a look at network panel (in firebug, or chrome dev tool) to see if this url is really fetched ?

Comment: Hm. I don't get any output in the Network panel (using Chrome). Shouldn't there be a 404 if it isn't fetched?

Comment: Any console error ? And make sure `$` is available in your function : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers

Answer (score 1):

Well, no console error, no network query :

- it is not a WPML issue
- did you check #content really exists ?

Answer (score 0):

In chrome dev tool, go to Network, and trigger your function. You'll see what you receive.

Comment: I only get "No requests captured."